# Spark in fine-grained mode hold resources even it is idle and it doesn't perform any actions

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I start Spark in fine-grained mode with Mesos cluster manager.

```
spark-shell.sh --conf 'spark.mesos.coarse=false' --executor-memory 20g --driver-memory 5g
```

And i can see on Mesos UI that it doesn't use any resources which is fine. Then i perform some action and during action is performing Spark uses all cluster resources which is also fine.

But when action is done Spark still holds some CPU and memory forever.

Why Spark still need some resources if it is idle and it doesn't perform any actions and how can i release all resources if it is idle?

Comment: Are you running Spark streaming application? I doubt yes.

Comment: No, it is not streaming application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try configuring e.g. `spark.mesos.mesosExecutor.cores = 0.5` which limits number of cores used by each executor (in `fine-grained` mode).

You might consider lowering `executor-memory`, depending how is your job behaving.

Comment: It works, unfortunately i wasn't able to release all resources by these settings but i was able to decrease it significantly. The right name of settings is spark.mesos.mesosExecutor.cores

Comment: Is the memory actually used? You can try can smarter data caching (if you're transforming data you don't have to keep the original data loaded in memory).